# Get object properities?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var skillet = {

   age: '20',

   names: { 

      first: 'abe',
      last: 'watson',
      additional: "<div>'" + age + "'</div>"

   }

};
```

I am getting stuck on the `age` in that it says its `undefined` ? I have also tried `skillet.age` in the `names` property that doesn't work. How can I include the `age` within `names` ?

Comment: ? this works  `alert(skillet.age);`

Comment: @MikeL.: It's the use of `age` within the `additional` property initializer that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `age` you refer to in your `names` object is a reference to a free variable that isn't in scope. There is no way, within an object literal, to refer to another of the object literal's properties directly. You'd have to do this:

```
var skillet = {

   age: '20',

   names: { 

      first: 'abe',
      last: 'watson'
   }

};
skillet.names.additional = "<div>'" + skillet.age + "'</div>";
```

Comment: @Andy: `this` would refer to whatever `this` happened to refer to in the containing scope. It is **not** set to `skillet` within the object literal. There is no symbol available to refer to `skillet` from within the literal itself. The right-hand-side of the property initializers is performed as `skillet` is created. You may be thinking of `this` in relation to using it within a *function* that you've assigned to a `skillet` property, but that's a completely different thing that happens later when that function is *called*.

Comment: ah crapola - ok so I need something like what you've written ? I had hoped to do something like `skillet.global = { loadingUrl: 'url', ajax: "<div>'" + loadingUrl + "'</div>' }` but it seems I cant ? instead must use `skillet.global = { loadingUrl: 'url' } skillet.global.ajax = "<div>'" + loadingUrl + "'</div>';` ?

Comment: @Andy: Correct, you can't, and you probably wouldn't want to even if you could, as it would set `ajax` using the value of `loadingUrl` at the time `ajax` was initialized, not its *current* value when you read the `ajax` property. If you want `ajax` to return whatever the *current* value of `loadingUrl` i, you'll need to make it a function: `skillet.global = { loadingUrl: 'url', ajax: function() { "<div>'" + loadingUrl + "'</div>'" } };` (http://pastie.org/3436980), which you would then call as `skillet.global.ajax()` (with the parens).

Answer (score 1):

When you reach `additional`, the `skillet` object is not defined yet. You have to define the property *after* the creation of `skillet`:

```
var skillet = {    
   age: '20',
   names: { 
      first: 'abe',
      last: 'watson'
      //additional: "<div>'" + age + "'</div>"
   }
};
skillet.names.additional = '<div>' + skillet.age + '</div>';
```